# Best way for inter-cluster communication between microservices on Kubernetes?

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, microservices, kubernetes-ingress

I want to understand what is the best way I can implement below behaviour in microservices deployed on Kubernetes :

There are 2 different K8s clusters. Microservice B is deployed on both the clusters.

Now if a Microservice A calls Microservice B and B’s pods are not available in cluster 1, then the call should go to B of cluster 2.

I could have imagined to implement this functionality by using Netflix OSS but here I am not using it.

Also, keeping aside the inter-cluster communication aside for a second, how should I communicate between microservices ?

One way that I know is to create Kubernetes Service of type NodePort for each microservice and use the IP and the nodePort in the calling microservice.

Question : What if someone deletes the target microservice's K8s Service? A new nodePort will be randomly assigned by K8s while recreating the K8s service and then again I will have to go back to my calling microservice and change the nodePort of the target microservice. How can I decouple from the nodePort?

I researched about kubedns but seems like it only works within a cluster.

I have very limited knowledge about Istio and Kubernetes Ingress. Does any one of these provide something what I am looking for ?

Comment: Why not setup a virtual network and allow certain subdomains to communicate to each other using Endpoint IP address. E.g In Azure world, create vnet and vnet gateway for each kubernates cluster and then create a Connection between them. We have done that on GCP and Azure. Worked beautifully.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can expose you application using services, there are some kind of services you can use:

> - `ClusterIP`: Exposes the Service on a cluster-internal IP. Choosing this value makes the Service only reachable from within the cluster. This is the default  `ServiceType`.
> - [`NodePort`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport): Exposes the Service on each Node’s IP at a static port (the  `NodePort`). A  `ClusterIP`  Service, to which the  `NodePort`  Service routes, is automatically created. You’ll be able to contact the  `NodePort`  Service, from outside the cluster, by requesting  `<NodeIP>:<NodePort>`.
> - [`LoadBalancer`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer): Exposes the Service externally using a cloud provider’s load balancer.  `NodePort`  and  `ClusterIP`  Services, to which the external load balancer routes, are automatically created.
> - [`ExternalName`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname): Maps the Service to the contents of the  `externalName`  field (e.g.  `foo.bar.example.com`), by returning a  `CNAME`  record

For **internal communication** you  an use service type `ClusterIP`, and you could configure the service dns for your applications instead an IP.
I.e.: a service called `my-app-1` could be reach internnaly using the dns `http://my-app-1` or with fqdn `http://my-app-1.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local`.

For **external communication**, you can use `NodePort` or `LoadBalancer`.

`NodePort` is good when you have few nodes and know the ip of all of them. And yes, by the [service docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) you can specify a specific port number:

> If you want a specific port number, you can specify a value in the `nodePort` field. The control plane will either allocate you that port or report that the API transaction failed. This means that you need to take care of possible port collisions yourself. You also have to use a valid port number, one that’s inside the range configured for NodePort use.

`LoadBalancer` give you more flexibility, because you don't need to know all node ips, you just must to know the service IP and port. But `LoadBalancer` is only supported in cloudproviders, if you wan to implement in bare-metal cluster, I recomend you take a look in [MetalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf/).

Finally, there is another option that is use `ingress`, in my point of view is the best way to expose HTTP applications externally, because you can create rules by path and host, and it gives you much more flexibility than services. But **only** HTTP/HTTPS is supported, if you need TCP then go to Services.

I'd recommend you take a look in these links to understand in deep how services and ingress works:

[Kubernetes Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)

[Kubernetes Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/)

[NGINX Ingress](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking out time to answer. I can certainly not use a service of type LoadBalancer because I have bare metal Kubernetes clusters without any cloud providers. I don’t want to use NodePort type because if mS1 on cluster1 talks to mS2 on cluster2 and if mS2’s service gets deleted or the nodePort changes by any means then I will have to change the nodePort of mS2 in mS1’s config, which is a pain. I want to decouple from nodePort. ClusterIP will not be useful for me because I want inter-cluster service communication.

Comment: I was going through Istio, but turned out it uses the service discovery mechanism of native K8s only. I tried using Eureka and Ribbon for service discovery but turned out that the names of Kubernetes pods get registered in Eureka instead of Kubernetes services. So Ribbon does not understand the name of the pod. I am exploring Consul right now, but seems like it will pretty much behave like Eureka only. Should I write my own Service Discovery mechanism ? I could create a Service Registry microservice which will register all the microservices and then do a URL resolution using a custom client.

Comment: You can use LoadBalancer type in bare-metal cluster, you just need to install MetalLB. With MetalLB you can configure a ip range from your network and them the service will get this IP's and be accessible from your network. If any of this solutions isn't feasible to you, you could write your own service discovery. Give a chance to try MetalLB, maybe it help and save time to write your custom service discovery.

Comment: I did explore Metallb and I was so relieved when I first saw it. But as I was going through it's documentation, I found this :

"The majority of code changes, as well as the overall direction of the project, is a personal endeavor of one person, working on MetalLB in their spare time as motivation allows.

This means that, currently, support and new feature development is mostly at the mercy of one person’s availability and resources. You should set your expectations appropriately."

So I can obviously not use Metallb in my production systems.

Comment: I am thinking about trying out Consul and Linkerd. See what these can offer.

Answer (score 3):

Your design is pretty close to **Istio Multicluster** example.

By following the steps in the [Istio multicluster lab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/istio-multi-burst/#0) you'll get two clusters with one Istio control plane that balance the traffic between two ClusterIP Services located in two independent Kubernetes clusters.

The lab's [configuration](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/istio-multi-burst/#7) watches the traffic load, but rewriting the Controller Pod code you can configure it to switch the traffic to the Second Cluster if the Cluster One's Service has no endpoints ( all pods of the certain type are not in Ready state).

It's just an example, you can change `istiowatcher.go` [code](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/istio-multi-burst/#16) to implement any logic you want.

---

There is [more advanced solution](https://istio.io/blog/2020/multi-cluster-mesh-automation/) using **Admiral** as an Istio Multicluster management automation tool.

> Admiral provides automatic configuration for an Istio mesh spanning multiple clusters to work as a single mesh based on a unique service identifier that associates workloads running on multiple clusters to a service. It also provides automatic provisioning and syncing of Istio configuration across clusters. This removes the burden on developers and mesh operators, which helps scale beyond a few clusters.

This solution solves these key requirements for modern Kubernetes infrastructure:

- Creation of service DNS entries decoupled from the namespace, as described in Features of multi-mesh deployments.
- Service discovery across many clusters.
- Supporting active-active & HA/DR deployments. We also had to support these crucial resiliency patterns with services being deployed in globally unique namespaces across discrete clusters.

This solution may become very useful in a full scale.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please go through the discussion down below with @KoopaKiller ? It has more insights of what I exactly want. Appreciate your help !

Comment: I've read all your comments, and I believe the lab answers on almost all your questions if you spend some time to do all steps. It can be a bit more complicated to do it on premise, but I'm sure GCP free tier is enough to complete the lab.

Answer (score 1):

Use ingress for inter cluster communication and use cluster ip type service for intra cluster communication between two micro services.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Could you please go through the comments which I posted above in reply to KoopaKiller ?